# Tensorflow ValueError: Too many vaues to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime-error, generator, mnist

I have looked this up on Reddit, Stack Overflow, tech forums, documentation, GitHub issues etc etc and still can't solve this issue.

For reference, I am using `Python 3 TensorFlow` on Windows 10, 64 Bit.

I am trying to use my own dataset (300 pics of cats, 512x512, .png format) in `Tensorflow` to train it to know what a cat looks like. If this works I will train it with other animals and eventually objects.

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. The error appears in the line `images,labal = create_batches(10)`, which points to my function `create_batches` (see below). I don't know what could be causing this as I am fairly new to `TensorFlow`. I am trying to make my own Neural Network based on the MNIST Dataset. Code below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import cv2


content = []
labels_list = []
with open("data/cats/files.txt") as ff:
    for line in ff:
        line = line.rstrip()
        content.append(line)

with open("data/cats/labels.txt") as fff:
    for linee in fff:
        linee = linee.rstrip()
        labels_list.append(linee)

def create_batches(batch_size):
    images = []
    for img in content:
        #f = open(img,'rb')
        #thedata = f.read().decode('utf8')
        thedata = cv2.imread(img)
        thedata = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(thedata)
        images.append(thedata)
    images = np.asarray(images)

    labels =tf.convert_to_tensor(labels_list,dtype=tf.string)

    print(content)
    #print(labels_list)

    while(True):
        for i in range(0,298,10):
            yield images[i:i+batch_size],labels_list[i:i+batch_size]


imgs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,262144])
lbls = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([262144,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(imgs,W) + b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(lbls * tf.log(y_),reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for i in range(10000):
    images,labal = create_batches(10)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={imgs:images, lbls: labal})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_,1),tf.argmax(lbls,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={imgs:content, lbls:labels_list}))
```

And the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Josh\Programming\Python\imgpredict\predict.py", line 54, in <module>

    images,labal = create_batches(2)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
(A few hundred lines of this)
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

My [GitHub link](https://github.com/supamonkey2000/jm-uofa) link if anyone needs it. The project folder is the "imgpredict".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are yielding your results in an incorrect way:

```
yield(images[i:i+batch_size]) #,labels_list[i:i+batch_size])
```

which gives you one value that is yielded, but when you call you method you are expecting two values yielded:

```
images,labal = create_batches(10)
```

Either yield two values , like:

```
yield (images[i:i+batch_size] , labels_list[i:i+batch_size])
```

(uncomment) or just expect one.

**Edit**: You should use parentheses on both the yield and when receiving the results like this:

```
#when yielding, remember that yield returns a Generator, therefore the ()
yield (images[i:i+batch_size] , labels_list[i:i+batch_size])

#When receiving also, even though this is not correct
(images,labal) = create_batches(10)
```

*However* this is not the way I have used the `yield` option; one usually iterates *over* your method that returns the generator, in your case it should look something like this:

```
#do the training several times as you have
for i in range(10000):
    #now here you should iterate over your generator, in order to gain its benefits
    #that is you dont load the entire result set into memory
    #remember to receive with () as mentioned
    for (images, labal) in create_batches(10):
        #do whatever you want with that data
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={imgs:images, lbls: labal})
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) question regarding the user of `yield` and generators.

Comment: I modified my code, but got the same error as before.

Comment: could you add the modified line here or edit the question?

Comment: `yield(images[i:i+batch_size],labels_list[i:i+batch_size])` and I also edited the question

Comment: See, you are still grouping all that with the parentheses, do it without it like in my answer

Comment: That is, it should be literally: `yield images[i:i+batch_size], labels_list[i:i+batch_size]`

Comment: I think I see it now. You should group the yield in parentheses *and* also receive it with parentheses, editing my answer now

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it. Look at my comment on the other answer for my current state

Comment: Did it remove the "Too many values to unpack"? If it did then it was a solution for this question, if you are getting new errors you should post a new question or work through them before.

Comment: it got me partially through. It was meant to debug, not fix. Still getting the same error though my program is making it partway through the loop. I can post a new question since I *guess* its a new problem

Comment: I just noticed that maybe you are using the `yield` operator in a wrong way. Checking some of my codes, the way I used `yield` was rather different, I am going to edit my answer to show you how... hope it helps

Comment: Ok, do check also the link I mentioned to the other question, I believe it will greatly help you understand more about generators and the `yield` keyword

Comment: Alright! That fixed the first error, now I have one on the `sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={imgs:images, lbls: labal})` line, but that's for another question. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Great I could help :) also remember to upvote if you found useful my answer. Good luck with your coding

Comment: I upvoted but my rep isn't high enough to be displayed. Thanks for the luck, I'm going to need it

Answer (score 0):

You commented out the second return item.

```
        yield(images[i:i+batch_size])    #,labels_list[i:i+batch_size])
```

You yield a single list to assign to `images`, and there's nothing left for `labal`.  Remove that comment mark, or yield a dummy value if you're in debugging mode.

---

**UPDATE**

Separate this line and check what you're trying to return:

```
result = (images[i:i+batch_size],
          labels_list[i:i+batch_size])
print len(result), result
return result
```

Comment: Oh... Forgot about that. I'll have to check that at home, my work shift just ended. If that fixes it I'll go insane

Comment: If you're entering a state of insanity, remember to bring a valid passport, so you can get home when you're done visiting.  It's an interesting place to visit, but not somewhere you want to raise your kids.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the issue (I remote desktopped into my system). I get the same error as before.

Comment: So I tested it out. Turns out my program can get through the first 3 batches (it outputs "result" to my 30th image), then it decides to stop working. Any idea why?

Comment: Not without the concommitant data and results, no.  What I gave you is a help in debugging, not a solution.

Comment: I'm aware that it is a debugging line, and it did help me debug that my program is *partially* completing a loop, so it did help. When I get home I can post the full results of the "result" output

Comment: Thanks; I wanted to make sure you were clear on that part.

Comment: Thanks for the help with debugging my for loop, I have cleared up my error. I have a new error, but thats for a new question. Once again thanks :)